# Reputation not updating after an upvote

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki, up-votes

This morning when I used the Stack Overflow login my reputation was 966. At lunch time I answered a question and obtained an upvote, but my reputation has not been changed.

The question is [After Adding quickblox-android-0.8.1.jar file in project libs folder and getting error when install on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482426/after-adding-quickblox-android-0-8-1-jar-file-in-project-libs-folder-and-getting/16538568)

What is the issue?

Comment: You marked the post as "Community wiki", which is why no reps are assigned to your account for that answer. There is a checkbox below the answer text area, for marking the post as "Community wiki".

Comment: @AzizShaikh why any document about this.

Comment: Tooltip is displayed when you take your mouse on the "Community wiki" label of the checkbox. Detailed info is available at [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: @AzizShaikh thank i see that but what is the problem.please any document of stk to better understand the reason?please provide me i want know the process of "Community wiki".

Comment: @AzizShaikh - Actually the OP didn't make his post as Community Wiki, because when he answered, the question was already CW.

Comment: CW == Community Wiki

Comment: @hims056 I guess you are correct, maybe I missed that part. One answer was not a CW so I assumed that Zala marked it as CW.

Comment: @AzizShaikh - Yeah that was my first guess too. But when I see the question as a CW, I checked it's revision and found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is marked **[Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)**, therefore it doesn't accumulate reputation.

### Documentation:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) - [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry.
- [Community Wiki privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki)